# mysql exception in copying data from grid view to database table

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, datagridview

i have a data grid view i want to copy data from data grid view to database table , it throws mysql exception,please help here is my code

```
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null) //if id is not null
            {
                string mysqlStatement = "INSERT INTO test1(Paper, Authors, ID, GSCitations) VALUES('" + row.Cells[0].Value + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value + "','" + row.Cells[2].Value + "','" + row.Cells[3].Value + "');";
                MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(mysqlStatement, connection);
                mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Incorrect integer value: 'grouping verifiable content selective disclosure ' for column 'ID' at row 1 is error

Comment: could you paste the mysql exception here?

Comment: Seems like row.Cells[0].Value is an invalid id at row 133.

Comment: now i see that there is no id which is 133 i have id upto 132,why didn't the loop stop at 132?

Comment: don't know. i have no expirience with c#...

Comment: @mani1989 in you `if ` statement, try this, `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells[0].Value)) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a big chance that the record contains `single quote`. And that your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`.

Please do parameterized the query:

- to avoid from `SQL Injection`
- to avoid from `SQL Injection` `:D`

code snipet:

```
string mysqlStatement = @"INSERT INTO test1(Paper, Authors, ID, GSCitations) 
                            VALUES(@paper, @Authors, @ID, @GSCitations)";

MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(mysqlStatement, connection);
mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string connStr = "connection string here";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using (MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = mysqlStatement;
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paper", row.Cells[0].Value);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Authors", row.Cells[1].Value);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Cells[2].Value);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GSCitations", row.Cells[3].Value);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comm.ExcuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(MySqlException e)
        {
            // do something with
            // e.ToString()  // this is the exception
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see:

- the code uses `Try-Catch` block to properly handle exception
- uses `using` statement for proper object disposal